# pip upgrade on dotcloud push

Tags: pip, dotcloud

Is it possible to force the builder to use the pip `--upgrade` flag when performing a push?

I seem to have an issue where there is a dependency that isn't being upgraded. I have changed the dependency in my requirements.txt file to use a git repository containing a bug fix rather than pypi but it doesn't seem to update it on the server as it's still getting errors.

Or is there a way to specify in the requirements file? I have checked the pip documentation but couldn't find an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

What does your dependency line look like in your requirements file? Did you change the #egg value to something different to see if that helps?

If that doesn't work, you can try one of these:

- You could do the pip install --upgrade in your `postinstall` script
  so that you can upgrade the bad package, and then once upgraded you
  could remove from `postinstall`.
- Another option would be to ssh into the service directly, remove the
  old dependency and then install the new one.

Comment: I haven't worked with eggs previously, so can you explain if I change the #egg value to something different, will I need to change the imports in my code?

Comment: @MarkUnsworth no, the egg value is just for the install packages, your code will stay the same.